# How to go to end of match using search-backward-regexp?

Tags: regular-expressions, search, point

I am trying to match a regex using this code

```
(search-backward-regexp "\n[\t\n ]*?\n" nil "NOERROR" 1)
```

search-backward-regexp documenation says

> Set point to the beginning of the match, and return point.

How can I set point to end of match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running the search, go to `match-end`. (Included fix from Dan's answer)

```el
(when (search-backward-regexp "\n[\t\n ]*\n" nil 'noerror)
  (goto-char (match-end 0)))
```

From the docstring of `search-backward-regexp`:

> See also the functions `match-beginning`, `match-end`, `match-string`, and `replace-match`.

Comment: Are `see also functions` generated programmatically or documented manually?

Comment: @ChillarAnand they are manually written in the docstring.

Answer (score 2):

This is a minor modification to @Malabarba's answer.  It only goes to `match-end` if your search succeeds.  Otherwise, the `goto-char` will send you off to wherever you had a successful match on a prior regexp search (whether you initiated it, or some other function used it under the hood), which could lead to astonishing jumps.

```el
(when (search-backward-regexp "\n[\t\n ]*\n" nil 'noerror)
  (goto-char (match-end 0)))
```

Probably best to wrap this in a function.